# list out image extension support in android 

Tags: android

I would like to know that which `extension` of image are supported in android?
can you give me list of `image extension` support by android

Thanks
nik

Comment: Please check below link my be helpful to you http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image Extensions Supported in Android

JPEG
GIF
PNG
BMP

Well You can refer Here

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html